# Is it possible to have SVG elements placed in reference to HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I would like to use HTML (MathJax or something similar ideally) for my main layout, but I want to overlay lines with arrows on top that connect explanations for various things to the things they're explaining.

For example, I want to demonstrate Euclid's algorithm by showing all the different divisions that happen with arrows that show how the results from one division feed into the next one.

My thought is to use MathJax for the math and SVG to draw the lines with the arrows. Is there a better way to do this? Is it even possible if you don't know precisely where (or don't want to specify to account for different browsers and different layouts) the elements are going to be placed?

Comment: You can use getBoundingClientRect to find the bounding boxes of things then connect accordingly.

Comment: @RobertLongson - How do I tell SVG to use the same coordinate system as the HTML page it's embedded in? Or, alternatively, is there a Javscript function that will translate the coordinate systems for me?

Comment: Maybe this can give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962714/how-to-setup-svg-to-change-position-when-resizing-the-window/45967077#45967077 It uses [d3.js] to dynamically append the annotations, but the resize event listener should be readable disregarding the lib.